# How can I make background color of canvas white with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, canvas

### What I want to do

I want to know how to make background color white.

I built a drawing app with canvas. You can download the canvas image you have drawn by clicking the Download button. But its background color is black (technically transparent).

How can I change it to white?

---

### What I tried

I added the following code to my code, but it didn't work well. I couldn't draw anything.

```
ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

---

### Here is my code

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('#draw');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.strokeStyle = '#BADA55';

  ...

function draw(e) {
  if (!isDrawing) return;
  console.log(e);
  ctx.strokeStyle = `hsl(${hue}, 100%, 50%)`;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
  ctx.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
  ctx.stroke();
  [lastX, lastY] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];

  ...

}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDrawing = true;
  [lastX, lastY] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);

  ...

downloadBtn.addEventListener('click', downloadImage);
function downloadImage() {
  if (canvas.msToBlob) {
    const blob = canvas.msToBlob();
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
  } else {
      downloadLink.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      downloadLink.download = filename;
      downloadLink.click();
  }
}
```

I want to make background color of downloaded image white.

Comment: You tried `ctx.fillRect()`, but it's not in your code. Where did you put it?

Comment: I removed ctx.fillRect(). I'll post the same question with more details later because I don't still have privilege for editing my question.

Comment: What do you mean you don't have the privilege to [edit] your question. This is no privilege, at 1 rep you already can. Closing the other one as dupe of this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to set background color of canvas.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.fillStyle = "green";
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

```css
canvas{ border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas width=300 height=150 id="canvas">
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but I tried your code before. I couldn't draw anything on the canvas with my mouse. It didn't work as a drawing app. The canvas only showed green.

Comment: I don't still have privilege for editing my question. I'll post the same question with more details later.

Answer (score 0):

On a canvas you can use `getAttribute()` to retrieve the dimension. Look at my snippet:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let cheight = parseInt(canvas.getAttribute("height"));
let cwidth = parseInt(canvas.getAttribute("width"));

let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.fillStyle = "green";
context.fillRect(0,0,cwidth,cheight);
```

```html
<canvas width="200" height="200" id="canvas">
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but I tried your code before. I couldn't draw anything on the canvas with my mouse. It didn't work as a drawing app. The canvas only showed green.

Comment: Then there is probably something wrong with your drawing code and you should open another question.

Comment: I don't still have privilege for editing my question. I'll post the same question with more details later. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

In your `draw()` function you need to add specifically the background like this:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('#draw');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.strokeStyle = '#BADA55';
ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff"; //HERE, use HEX format in 6 digits
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //HERE

 ...

function draw(e) {
    ...
}
```

### Why?

> You need to draw the background before everything, otherwise drawing the background over and over, or also above everything would result in the white rectangle overlapping everything on your canvas.

Here is a [LIVE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/k3llydev/qy9ntsgL/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I copied and pasted your code in my code. Then I couldn't draw anything. I think I should've shown more my code. I was advised to open another question. I'll post the same question with more details later.

Comment: @MiuTaji I managed to analyze your code and brought you the solution. It is in the live demo. Now the image is downloaded with a white background. Please let me know if it helped.

Comment: Thank you very much for LIVE DEMO. I think something is wrong with my drawing code. I added `ctx.fillStyle` and `ctx.fillRect` to the same place as you did. I've opened another question with more detail. I'd appreciate it if you could check and answer it as well. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56175553/11451181?sem=2)