# How can I make background color of downloaded canvas image white in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

### What I want to do

I want to know how to make background color white.

I built a drawing app with canvas. You can draw on the canvas by moving mouse while holding down the left click.

You can also download the canvas image you have drawn by clicking the Download button. But its background color is black (technically transparent).

How can I change it to white?

**I posted the same question before this. I was advised to open another question because most of the code is missing in my previous question. This question has more details.**

---

### What I tried

I added the following code to my code, but it didn't work well. I couldn't draw anything.

```
ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

---

### Here is my code

#### HTML

```html
<button class="btn--download">Download</button>
<canvas id="draw" width="640" height="640"></canvas>
<a id="download_link"></a>
```

#### CSS

```css
#draw {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  box-shadow: 0 0.1rem 0.5rem 0.1rem rgba(43, 12, 1, 0.1);
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
// Canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector('#draw');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.strokeStyle = '#BADA55';
ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'hue';
// ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
// ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
// I removed fillStyle & fillRect because I couldn't draw anything due to them.

let isDrawing = false;
let lastX = 0;
let lastY = 0;

function draw(e) {
  if (!isDrawing) return; // Stop the fn from running when they are not moused down.
  console.log(e);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
  ctx.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
  ctx.stroke();
  [lastX, lastY] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDrawing = true;
  [lastX, lastY] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => isDrawing = false);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', () => isDrawing = false);

// Save as Image
const downloadBtn = document.querySelector('.btn--download');
const downloadLink = document.querySelector('#download_link');
const locale = new Date().toLocaleString();
const filename = `doodle${locale}.png`;
downloadBtn.addEventListener('click', downloadImage);
function downloadImage() {
  if (canvas.msToBlob) {
    const blob = canvas.msToBlob();
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
  } else {
      downloadLink.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      downloadLink.download = filename;
      downloadLink.click();
  }
}
```

I want to make background color of downloaded image white.

---

[k3llydev](/questions/tagged/k3llydev)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I mention on my previous answer, I found what is causing this issue with your code.

After adding:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

What is making conflict with your code is this particular line:

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'hue';
```

What this does is it preserves the luma and chroma of the bottom layer, while adopting the hue of the top layer.

> As I see your code, the thing is that you don't really need to use this kind of layering since you will only draw lines. So, try to removing it or replacing it with another layering type that can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation).

**See it working here:**

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#draw');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.strokeStyle = '#BADA55';
ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

let isDrawing = false;
let lastX = 0;
let lastY = 0;

function draw(e) {
  if (!isDrawing) return; // Stop the fn from running when they are not moused down.
  console.log(e);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
  ctx.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
  ctx.stroke();
  [lastX, lastY] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDrawing = true;
  [lastX, lastY] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => isDrawing = false);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', () => isDrawing = false);

// Save as Image
const downloadBtn = document.querySelector('.btn--download');
const downloadLink = document.querySelector('#download_link');
const locale = new Date().toLocaleString();
const filename = `doodle${locale}.png`;
downloadBtn.addEventListener('click', downloadImage);
function downloadImage() {
  if (canvas.msToBlob) {
    const blob = canvas.msToBlob();
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
  } else {
      downloadLink.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      downloadLink.download = filename;
      downloadLink.click();
  }
}
```

```css
#draw {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  box-shadow: 0 0.1rem 0.5rem 0.1rem rgba(43, 12, 1, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn--download">Download</button>
<canvas id="draw" width="640" height="640"></canvas>
<a id="download_link"></a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and detalied explanation! I've fixed the problem finally! By the way, I like `globalCompositeOperation = 'hue';`. I think mixed colors by 'hue' are beautiful. Can't I use 'hue'? I've put 'darken' instead of 'hue'. But I still prefer 'hue'.

Comment: @MiuTaji Always glad to help. And answering your question, what I would do to achieve this using hue would be saving the drawn pattern in a different layer or kind of *re-draw* it every time a new line has been drawn. Also, don't forget to vote and accept an answer in your other question since this was marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Remove this line

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'hue';
```

This is what makes your strokes white on a white background.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I've fixed the problem finally! By the way, I like `globalCompositeOperation = 'hue';`. Mixed colors by 'hue' are beautiful. Can't I use 'hue'?

Comment: @MiuTaji, the hue preserves the chroma (or saturation) of the bottom layer i.e. your white background, which will make your stroke layer white too, eventhough it's color(hue) is different. You would see the same effect if your background was black.